# Is it safe (or good programming style) to initialize a lazy var with nil vars?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, lazy-initialization

Let me explain a little better what I mean since it's kinda tricky to understand.

I'm creating a prototype for a videogame. Every level inherits the main rules from a `SKScene` called `SceneLogic`:

```
class SceneLogic: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    // Set up the physics, the contacts, touches and so on...
}

class Level1: SceneLogic { }
class Level2: SceneLogic { }
```

Every level has its own `.sks` file which specifies the different icon to show in the HUD. In order to create a kind of "game engine" I thought to init every kind of graphics inside the `SceneLogic` class by `lazy var` and ignore them if the current level doesn't need it.

Let me explain with an example

```
class SceneLogic: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    // Text, available only for level 1
    private lazy var textTopHUD = childNode(withName: "textTop") as! SKLabelNode

    // Icon, available only for levels 3,4,5
    private lazy var iconBottomHUD = childNode(withName: "iconBottom") as! SKSpriteNode

    // Icon, available only for level 2
    private lazy var iconLeftHUD = childNode(withName: "iconLeft") as! SKSpriteNode


    func initGame(level: Int) {
        switch mode {
            case 1: // Level 1
                textTopHUD.text = "Level 1"
            case 2: // Level 2
                iconLeftHUD.position = ....
        }
    }
}
```

The fact is: for level 1, `iconBottomHUD` is `nil`, for level 2 `textTopHUD` is `nil`... but the app doesn't crash since the var is `lazy` and it won't be called for some levels.

My question is: is it a good programming style? Is it safe to use `lazy` in this way?

Comment: Why do you suspect it is not safe?

Comment: Why don't you add those fields only to the `LevelN` classes to which they're relevant?

Comment: @Sweeper I just started using `lazy` vars and I'm still trying to understand their potential and their weakness :) I asked 'cause I was afraid to miss something and create some issues in the code

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Yep, that could be a better way to achieve it but I wanted to handle the methods without repeating myself. Further in the code I'll add some methods for handling score, time, and so on...

Comment: The point of `lazy vars` is to make initialization faster by deferring the heavy task to another moment in time when you would need it, for this case, since you know that you are not even going to use them (that is different that the possibility of them being there, just not now), i would change the implementation to a `Protocol` oriented way.

Comment: @javierrivarola Interesting answer, thanks! Would you mind to give me a little example using `Protocol` in this case?

Comment: You could make a `HUDDisplayable` protocol , then you can inherit from that for the 3 types of `huds` like `protocol HUDTopDisplayable: HUDDisplayable {}` , `protocol HUDBottomDisplayable: HUDDisplayable {}` and so on, and then you can make default implementations for them, if you share the same implementation for all huds, and only adopt the protocol that your Scene will need

Comment: @user3582537 Those sound like protocols to me. Or rather, entire classes, which contains SKSpriteNodes or whatever indside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about lazy properties is that it defers the execution of the initialization code. So in your case it doesn't really matter since they are actually nil. So you `defer` the `init` of nothing basically. If i were you i would basically either make it as a computed propert as such:

```
private lazy var iconBottomHUD: SKSpriteNode = {
      guard let node = childNode(withName: "iconBottom") as? SKSpriteNode else {
          fatalError()
      }
      return node
}
```

Or make it as @JavierRivarola mentioned, make it protocol based.